# Migrate previously closed question to Gaming?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration, gaming

Now that https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ exists, can we migrate questions that were previously closed as off-topic because they are related to gaming to it? Specifically, I'd like to move [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/142981/what-games-work-well-on-macbook-pro-i7-geforce-gt-330m-within-vmware-fusion-c). I could just copy and paste it as a new question, but that somehow feels wrong to me.

Comment: I know I probably got the support tag wrong, but I wasn't sure if this was support (since I have a specific request), or discussion (cause my specific request will be ignored). Please correct me as appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot migrate. At least not for now.

Best just copy and paste that sucker right into a new question o'er yonder at Gaming.

Or prod the OP if you don't want to have to select the best answer in its next life.

Comment: Pokity pokity poke...

Comment: Looks like it was already done about a month ago. Sometime before the migration paths were in. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/what-games-work-well-on-macbook-pro-i7-geforce-gt-330m-within-vmware-fusion @bad